# How does the mass composition affect the empirical formula?

Tags: mass-spectrometry, structural-formula

I have to do an assignment of [empirical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_formula), and how different percentage [mass compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_fraction_(chemistry)) affect the formula obtained, from experimental data.

We did three trials and 2 of which of the same compounds ([copper chloride hydrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_chloride)), has different mass compositions.

I can't find any information about how mass composition affect the empirical formula, although I do understand i need extra proof to explain all the little detail behind it all.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me thank you so much !!!

Comment: From Googling "mass composition to empirical formula": https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/chemical-reactions-stoichiome/empirical-molecular-formula/v/formula-mass-composition  There are a decent number of other examples if this isn't clear, but Khan academy generally does a good job.